# For every real $x \gt 0$ and every integer $n \gt 0$ there is one and only one real $y$ such that $y^n = x$.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm working through Rudin's proof of this theorem (1.21 in *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*) and I got stuck at a certain part. Here's the proof up until that part:

*Proof.*

That there is at most one such $y$ is clear since $0 \lt y_1 \lt y_2$ implies $y_1^n \lt y_2^n$.

Let $E$ be the set consisting of all positive real numbers $t$ such that $t^n \lt x$.

If $t = \frac{x}{1+x}$ then $0 \lt t \lt 1$ (I get this part since $1+x \gt x$ and $x \gt 0$). Hence $t^n \lt t \lt x$. (This is where Rudin lost me. First, how can $t$ be strictly greater than $t^n$ if it's not true for $n=1$. And is $t \lt x$ because $x = t(1+x)$?)

Help with this is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It’s only true with the condition that $y>0,$ too.

Comment: For $0 < t < 1$ and $n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}}$, you have that $t^n < t^{n-1} \times 1~$ [ since $t < 1$].  Therefore, you can prove by induction that $t^n < t.$

Comment: With $t = \frac{x}{x+1} ~: ~x>0$, you have that $(x+1) > 1 \implies t < \frac{x}{1}.$  In other words, since the denominator of $\frac{x}{x+1}$ is greater than the denominator of $\frac{x}{1}$, you have that $\frac{x}{x+1} < \frac{x}{1}.$

Comment: I think Rudin slipped up here $-$ $n=1$ should be treated as a special case (or it should be $t^n\le t< x$, if this is sufficient for the rest of the proof). And $t<x$ because $\frac{1}{1+x}<1$.

Comment: OP didn’t  exclude $y<0.$ @TonyK

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Can you elaborate further why it's true with the condition $y \gt 0$?

Comment: @user2661923 But it still doesn't show it's true for $n=1$. I think you're saying let $n \in \mathbf Z_{\ge2}$ and let $r = n -1$ where $r \gt 0$. But we need $n = 1$ to be true for $t^n \lt t \lt 1$, not $r =1$. Let me know if I'm misinterpreting.

Comment: When $n=1$, then $t^n = t$.  So, when $n = 1,$ it is **never** the case that $t^n < t$.

Comment: @user2661923 Right, and that's the trouble I'm finding myself in understanding Rudin's statement, unless it's just a typo in my textbook.

Comment: See the first comment of TonyK.  Another way of saying it is that since the assertion in your question's title is clearly true for $n=1$, and since it is assumed that $n \in \Bbb{Z^+}$ and that $y > 0$, you can assume without loss of generality that $n \geq 2.$

Comment: That is, if $x = 4$ and $n =2$, there are in fact two numbers, $y = -2$ and $y=2$ such that $y^2 = x$.  However, only one of those two numbers, namely $y = 2$, has $y > 0.$

Comment: @user2661923 OKAY your example clarified it for me. I agree I can assume without loss of generality that $n \ge 2$. Thank you!

Comment: I can elaborate why it is not true when you don’t require $y>0.$ Namely, $$(-2)^2=4=2^2.$$ @ash

Comment: I think TonyK has it.  Rudin considered the case where $n = 1$ as trivial (which it is:  Obviously there is a $y$ where $y^1 = x$; namely $x$ itself; and clearly $y$ is the only such such real number).  @ThomasAndrews "OP didn't exclude $y < 0$"  No.  But Rudin did.

Comment: " and that's the trouble I'm finding myself in understanding Rudin's statement, unless it's just a typo in my textbook."  It's not a typo.  But it's an oversight on Rudin's part.  Rudin *did* include a statement that it is clear that there can be at most one.  He should have included a second statement that it is also clear true that such a $y$ exists for $n = 1$ (namely $y = x$ itself).  Thus he is only proving it for $n > 1$ (but that is enough as for $n = 1$ it is clear.... I'm not sure the phrase "without loss of generality" is actually the correct phrase but... no need to belabor..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I grabbed my copy of "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" and I believe your confusion is justified. Rudin made a (small) mistake in the proof.

Rudin is simply trying to show that $E$ is non-empty and bounded above in this first part of the proof, which is hinted at by the fact that $t$ plays no further part afterwards. To that end he is trying to construct a number $t$ which would qualify to live in $E$. He goes ahead and constructs this $t$ as follows:
$$
t = \frac{x}{x+1}.
$$
From this we already have that $t < x$, since $0 < \frac{1}{x+1} < 1$, but we want $t^n < x$. Luckily for us, from the way $t$ has been constructed we know $0 < t < 1$. This means (and here is where Rudin made his mistake), $t^n \leq t < x$. The equality happens exactly when $n = 1$ as you pointed out. We still have $t^n < x$ regardless, and so the conclusion is still valid: $E$ is non-empty.

He makes the same mistake, again forgetting about $n = 1$, when goes about showing that $E$ is bounded above. A strict inequality must be replaced by a non-strict one. However, just like in the case above we are rescued by the fact that the claim $t^n \geq t > x$ still means that $t^n > x$.

However, there is also a much larger mistake. We also require $y > 0$ for the theorem to be true. I was honestly surprised Rudin didn't specify this in his statement of the theorem. He uses it in the proof.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much for the explanation; I suspected it was a mistake on Rudin’s part. Maybe there’s an errata out there with these fixes? I’ll check later...taking a break today.

Comment: I think calling this a "mistake" is a bit of an overstatement.  It is an oversight to not consider the trivial case $n=1$ but as $n=1$ *is* a trivial case (in both the literal and figurative sense of the word) considering it an error in need of a "fix" and to worry about confusion and inability for a student to follow the proof seems a bit of an overreaction to me.  I mean the proof clearly works for $n > 1$ so if any student does wonder "what if $n=1$" the *obvious* response is "well, what *if* $n=1$...?"  What happens then? And the answer should be obvious.

Comment: @fleablood and not explicitly stating that $y > 0$? Sorry, but if there are more “oversights” in Rudin’s text I might just switch over to Tao’s.